# magento:categories are not appearing when editing products

Tags: php, magento

I have one magento installation with 2 websites.I want to set a subcategory from website 1 as rootcategory of website 2. I copy
  app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Collection.php
to
  app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Collection.php

update around line 414

```
$this->addLevelFilter(1);
```

to

```
$this->addLevelFilter(2);
```

What this will do is when you go into System -> Manage Stores and click on the Store Name. It lets you set the Root Category. This dropdown will now not only display the root categories but also the level 2 categories. It's perfectly fine to use a subcategory as the root category in a certain store.
After that ,I create a sub-user who has the permission of manage products to manage the store which use a subcategory as the root category. when I log in by the sub-user and go to the products edit page , categories are not appearing.So that I can't set products' category. what I should do?

Comment: The normal way to do this is duplicate the categories from the subcategory of website 1 into a new root category. Then in the store view options for web site 2 you change the root category to the new one you just created. You shouldn't be copying and replacing files like you have either so undo that. It's not the magento way. I use a purchased module which handles advanced user permissions per store view and gives me the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: What is the module you have bought?

Comment: I use one by AITOC. It's http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_advanced_permissions.html

The license is a bit fiddly on setup but once working it's a pretty good module.

Comment: Thinks,I also use the AdvancedPermission plug-in now.However,there are some problems,too.